# How do I populate a table with Triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

[Image of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuFGc.png)

Hello,

I'm really new to sql and I only know the basics of it, so i am having some dificulties.

How do i populate tables with a trigger?. To be more specific i want to pass the primary key to another table, let's say for example i want to pass id_Academista (PK) from Table Academista to id_Academista (FK) on table Habilitacoes.

At this point i have something like this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADDCOMP 
AFTER INSERT ON ACADEMISTA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Habilitacoes(id_academista)
  VALUES((SELECT ID_ACADEMISTA FROM academista));
END;`

I test the code on Oracle, but i think it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You aren't far off - instead of `INSERT ... VALUES...`, use `INSERT ... SELECT...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `:new.id_Academista` in order to insert the value in other table. Try the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADDCOMP 
AFTER INSERT ON ACADEMISTA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Habilitacoes(id_academista)
  VALUES((:new.id_Academista));
END;
```

Here parameter `:new` represents the latest row you have inserted in the table `Academista` .